# When is the sex of a human not determined by their chromosomes?

Tags: human-genetics, sexual-reproduction

This might sound like a silly question, but what chromosomes determine whether a human is born a boy or a girl? I ask this because I got https://embryo.asu.edu/pages/sex-determination-humans when googling the subject and it contains the word "typically" in places I did not expect. For example:

1. > Humans **typically** develop as either male or female
2. > Humans who inherit two X chromosomes **typically** develop as females, while humans with one X and one Y chromosome **typically** develop as males.
3. > Because females tend to only have X chromosomes, the egg cells that they produce **typically** carry an X chromosome

Is this a form of political correctness, or are there legitimate cases that justify the insertion of the word **typically**? I'm genuinely curious what these exceptional cases might be.

Answer (score 9):

To answer points 1 and 2:

People born karyotypically male (XY) with [complete androgen insensitivity syndrome (AIS)](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/androgen-insensitivity-syndrome/), can be born without developed male genitals. People with a certain set of sex chromosomes develop in varying different ways.

To answer point three: An egg cell will indeed carry a single X chromosome in most cases, however, there are situations where an egg cell can carry **two** X chromosomes. If an egg cell containing two X chromosomes is fertilized with a sperm containing a Y chromosome then this could lead to XXY chromosomes — [Klinefelter syndrome](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/klinefelters-syndrome/).

Side notes:

For those interested in the impact of social standards regarding this syndrome, there is a good [interview with a Dutch person with AIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=888hOmfql1o). (One can set the translated captions to most languages.)

You can find information on the occurrence rate of intersex here:
[Intersex Society of North America](https://isna.org/faq/frequency/)

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

There is a a whole mess of inhibitors and activators proteins that need to be triggered for typical sexual development, a mutation or error in any one can lead to atypical results even if they have typical chromosomes. A graphical overview is below. You may note than several factors are common to both sexes. [Atypical can range from just malformation of genitals to full on sex reversal. XY female and XX male exist.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5866176/)  Then you have all the atypical chromosome combinations, Xo, XXX, XYY, XXYY, ect. A full breakdown of most the known options (as of 2016) can be found [here](https://www.karger.com/Article/Fulltext/452637). And that's just the gross physical manifestations, [the brain has largely separate pathways for sex determined development](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5286722/#:%7E:text=Brain%20development%20diverges%20in%20males,changes%20that%20profoundly%20impact%20behavior.), meaning an alteration of those pathways can lead to what is essentially [a male brain in a female body and vice versa](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18980961/).

[image]

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Sry-and-SoxE-genes%3A-How-they-participate-in-sex-and-She-Yang/3860ee65052aebecc48a85a79a36221160458b30

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5866176/